# How long should I schedule to travel from Manila to General Santos, Philippines?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, philippines, mnl

After flying in to Ninoy Aquino International Airport, Manila, how long should I plan to take using public transportation (bus?) to get to General Santos?

Comment: Before anyone asks, yes, I can read schedules. What I'm looking for is any known disruptions to travel in the next month or two; are the schedules firm, or known to be worthless, etc. I'm likely flying out in April 2015.

Comment: You do know there are a bunch of islands and salty-water puddles between the two cities, right? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of these flights are on so small airlines that it's hard to get historical performance data on but the [Philippine 453](http://www.flightstats.co.uk/FlightRating/flightRatingByFlight.do?airlineCode=PR&flightNumber=453&departureAirportCode=MNL&arrivalAirportCode=GES) flight out of 34 observations, 85% was on time, averaging only 9 minutes of delay, maximum 31 minutes of delay. So yes, the schedule is pretty firm.

[Rome2rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Manila/General-Santos) does show some bus connections but it's 1.5-2 days and does not show a significant savings over a flight taking less than 2 hours so I have not pursued this avenue further.

On further research I have found some outdated information on ferries going from Manila to Iloilo and on to General Santos taking even longer closer to three days. I haven't researched this either but the Wikipedia page on [2GO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2GO) reports it to be a modern fleet so one can presume it's on schedule.